# How to use env variables in npm scripts?

Tags: npm, environment-variables, package.json

I am trying to use env variable form file in package.json. All this commands return message "Unbound variable $NODE_ENV"

```
"scripts": {
  "xxx1": "dotenv -e ../.env echo $NODE_ENV",
  "xxx2": "env-cmd -f ../.env echo $NODE_ENV",
  "xxx3": "NODE_ENV=123 echo $NODE_ENV",
}
```

../.env:

```
NODE_ENV=123
```

- dotenv: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli
- env-cmd: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

`${NODE_ENV}` return same error. Looks like I do something wrong in the end of command. Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell expands the command to `dotenv -e ../.env echo`  before executing it, $NODE_ENV is expanded to empty text because it doesn't have a value yet.
The dotenv docs explain this issue: https://github.com/entropitor/dotenv-cli#variable-expansion-in-the-command

This script outputs 123 for me:
`dotenv -e ../.env -- bash -c 'echo $NODE_ENV'`